# Plims of matrices - plim X'X/n =Q

Tags: probability, econometrics

Let $X$ be a $n \times 2$ matrix with column 1 as a column of all 1's and column 2 a column of IID random variables $Z_1, Z_2,....Z_n$ where $Z_i$ is Bernoulli distributed with parameter $\theta$

What is the

$$\textrm{p}\lim_{n\to \infty
}  X′X/n$$ ?

Where $\textrm{p}\lim$ is [convergence in probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_probability).

The resulting matrix will of course be a $2 \times 2$ matrix with first element as 1, the 2nd element of the first row and 1st element of the second row are $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i Z_i$ and the last element is $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i(Z_i)^2$. What is the $\textrm{p}\lim$ of this matrix? And what value of $n$ will make it singular?

I know that since the $Z$'s are Bernoulli variables, their sum follows a binomial distribution and will have finite second moments. The $\textrm{p}\lim$ will therefore be a positive definite matrix. But I dont know what the matrix will be. Can someone help?

Comment: You can easily work it out, because $X^\prime X$ depends only on how many entries in the second column are ones: let's call that $K.$ You even know the distribution of $K$ (it is Binomial).  So write $X^\prime X$ in terms of $K$ and go on from there.

Comment: None of the entries in the second columns are 1. The entries in the second column of matrix X are bernoulli random variables Zi's each with parameter theta.

Comment: I am just wondering what the last element in the 2X2 matrix will converge to as n goes to infinity

Comment: You needn't wonder long, because three of the elements are always the same and the fourth one is a constant, so there's only one limit to work out.

Comment: the limit of the last term will just be E(Z^2) and the limits of the averages will be E(Z) as n goes to infinity - applying the WLLN.

Comment: Please observe that $Z^2=Z.$

Comment: Why is Z^2 = Z?

Comment: Because $0^2=0$ and $1^2=1$ and those are the only possible values $Z$ can have.

Answer (score 1):

Denote the sample mean by $\bar{Z}_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i$.  Expanding out the relevant expression for your design matrix, you can easily show that:

$$\frac{\mathbf{X}' \mathbf{X}}{n} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \bar{Z}_n \\
\bar{Z}_n & \bar{Z}_n \\ 
\end{bmatrix}.$$

(Note here that $Z_i$ is binary, so you have $\sum Z_i^2 = \sum Z_i$, which allows you to simplify the last element of the matrix to the above form.)
Since $Z_1, Z_2, Z_3, ... \sim \text{IID Bern}(\theta)$ it follows from the [weak law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Weak_law) that $\text{plim}_{n \rightarrow \infty} \bar{Z}_n = \theta$, which means you have:

$$\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\text{plim}} \text{ } \frac{\mathbf{X}' \mathbf{X}}{n} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \theta \\
\theta & \theta \\ 
\end{bmatrix}.$$